# String Equal to String Control Flow

Tags: javascript, if-statement, control-flow

When using `=` for the TDEE Calculation control flow comparison operators, the flow stops at `if (activityLevel = 'sedentary')`. When I use `==` it works as expected. I've been stuck on this for 2 hours and I've read about 3 documentations but I cant figure it out.

I know `==` is used for same value and meaning and `===` is used for same value and type, however I don't think that has anything to do with it. For a moment I thought maybe `=` is used for type, in this case if `activityLevel` equals a string, but I'm pretty sure thats not it either as I didn't come across that in documentations for `=`.

---

Note: The commented figures in the TDEE control flow are what the results *should* be, not what they are.

```
// REE Calculation
// Males - 10 x weight (kg) + 6.25 x height (cm) – 5 x age (y) + 5 = REE
// Females - 10 x weight (kg) + 6.25 x height (cm) – 5 x age (y) – 161 = REE

const gender = 'male'; // prompt('Are you male or female?');
const weight = 100; // prompt('How much do you weigh in KG?');
const height = 185; // prompt('What is your height in cm?');
const age = 23; // prompt('What is your age');

if (sex = 'male') {
    stepOne = 10 * weight;
    stepTwo = 6.25 * height;
    stepThree = 5 * age + 5;
    var ree = stepOne + stepTwo - stepThree;
}

if (sex = 'f') {
    stepOne = 10 * weight;
    stepTwo = 6.25 * height;
    stepThree = 5 * age - 161;
    var ree = stepOne + stepTwo - stepThree;
}

console.log(ree.toFixed(0)) // Answer is correct - 2171

// TDEE Calculation 

var activityLevel = 'moderate activity' // prompt('What is your activity level?\nsedentary/light activity/moderate activity/very active');

if (activityLevel = 'sedentary') {
    var tdee = ree * 1.2; // 2642.40
} else if (activityLevel = 'light activity') {
        var tdee = ree * 1.375; // 3027.75
    } else if (activityLevel = 'moderate activity') {
            var tdee = ree * 1.55; // 3413.10
        } else { // 3798.45
                var tdee = ree * 1.725;
            }   

console.log(tdee.toFixed(0))
```

Comment: sex = 'f' does not evaluate sex, it assigns the value 'f' to it.  Change it to be sex === 'f'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to get the type of something you can use the [typeof](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/typeof) operator. When you use the assignment operator (=) in your if-statement, it will always* pass the condition. If you want to check equality you should use the `==` or `===` operators.

for example, if you want to check the activity level you can do so by:

```
var activityLevel = 'moderate activity';
if (activityLevel === 'moderate activity'){
    console.log("Moderate Activity");
}
```

[This](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comparison_Operators?v=test) is a good document about the different operator in JS.

---

Update: Also just noticed that the variable `sex` is not defined. You defined `gender` at the beginning, but you are checking against the variable `sex`.

Comment: "*it will always pass the condition*" In most cases, but not quite always. It'll pass/fail the condition based on just the assigned value. Using `if (i = 0)`, for example, will fail the condition because `0` is *falsy*.

Comment: @JonathanLonowski is correct! that is why I put the asterisk on always :)

Comment: @NimaEsmailiMokaram Just noticed that sex is not defined. I was getting a bunch of red lines using ESLint, something about using `let` instead of `var`. I did a lot of tinkering and left for dinner, forgetting to change it back. Thanks for pointing that out!

Also, am I correct in understanding that I should use `=` when I want to run it on the variable to the left?

Comment: @Ibrahim `=` is the assignment operator, it puts the result of what is to its right to the variable on the left.